# jquery end prevent default() on final link on menu

Tags: jquery, if-statement

I've got a slide menu that seems to be working fine, the thing is if you select a link it works as it should do, if you select a link that has a child then the preventdefault() kicks in and it scrolls to it's child, i'm happy so far, but once you get to the end of the links as there's no more children, the link should work as normal but it doesn't.

here's the jquery

```
$(".menu li").click(function(e) {
    if($(this).children('.sub-menu').length > 0) {
        e.preventDefault();
        $(this).children('.sub-menu').addClass('open');
    }
    else  {
        $(".menu li").ready(function(){
            return true;
        });
    }
});
```

i've also attached a fiddle of it working.

http://jsfiddle.net/R6wHG/16/

Comment: Sorry just added it, you were too quick for me lol.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem is that you're binding the event handlers to the `<li>` elements, and clicks on `<a>` elements propagate up the DOM. When you click on the link, it bubbles from that link up to the `<li>` (which doesn't contain a sub-menu), then eventually up to another `<li>` which *does* contain a sub-menu, and at that point the default behaviour of that click event (following the link) is suppressed. Bind your event handler to the `<a>` elements themselves, and check to see if the next element is a `.sub-menu` one:

```
$(".menu a").click(function (e) {
    if ($(this).next('.sub-menu').length > 0) {
        e.preventDefault();
        $(this).next('.sub-menu').addClass('open');
    }
});
```

[Updated jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/R6wHG/18/)

Comment: Thank you soooo much, been stuck on this for what seems like for ever, i've now got another slight issue with the back button, thought this was working fine, but when you go 2 levels up, the back button goes back to the start and not 1 level down, so i'll need to fix this now, here goes again lol. but thanks for that

Answer (score 3):

You also need to `stopPropagation()` as `preventDefault()` was being called on the parent `li` elements:

```
$(".menu li").click(function (e) {
    e.stopPropagation();
    if ($(this).children('.sub-menu').length > 0) {
        e.preventDefault();
        $(this).children('.sub-menu').addClass('open');
    }
});
```

[**Example fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/RoryMcCrossan/sAKxn/)

Note I also removed `return true` as it was redundant.

Comment: Hi this also worked but there was more of an issue with the back button, if you go up 1 level, the back button did not work until you went down a level and back up again.

Comment: @Dan no problem, Anthony's solution is better anyway, as you should put the click handler directly on the element raising the event, not a parent it's bubbling through.